# Flexdashboard navbar colors

Tags: css, r, flexdashboard

[I have navbar like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WX42.png)

CSS code is

```
.navbar {
background-color:yellow;
border-color:black;
}
```

How I can change that blue thing with tells active page?
EDIT:
I have rmarkdown file and that css-file is myfile.css

````
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    css: mystyle.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Plots
===================================== 

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


Table
===================================== 

Heatmap
=====================================
````

Comment: Hi! Please provide the full css code you tried and Explain what you want more in brief.

Comment: Hi!

That is full css. I have tried google what would be right command but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

The active page probably has a class with "active" or "active-page". If so, you can style the class for example:

```
.active {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Okay, could you show me your html? and maybe also the javascript file?

Comment: I have only almost blank rmakdown file with does that. I'll put it on my orginal post.